# Representing $\{x | Ax = b\}$ as the nullspace plus an offset

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

During a class on linear algebra my prof wrote $$\{x | Ax = b\} = x_p + N(A), x\in \mathbb{R}^n, A  \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$$ (exactly as written)

For the last two hours I have been trying to understand how you can go from left hand side to right hand side in non-hand wavy style as was demonstrated in the lecture.

The prof is a good mathematician so I don't think he made a mistake, so the problem is me. I hope someone can help me out.

Here's my confusion:

---

Let $Ax_p = b$, and $Ax_n = 0$,

then $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n  | Ax = b\} = \{x_p \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_p = b\}\cup \{x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_n = 0\} $

At the final step I just do not feel comfortable writing $\{x_p \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_p = b\}\cup \{x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_n = 0\} = x_p + N(A)$

First:  $\{x_p \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_p = b\} \neq x_p$

Second: $\{x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_n = 0\} \neq N(A) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax = 0\}$

Third: $\{x_p \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_p = b\}\cup \{x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_n = 0\} \neq \{x_p \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_p = b\} + \{x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_n = 0\}$

Can someone please point me to the right direction and show me how this relation can be made true?

Comment: It's not true that any $x_n$ for which $Ax_n = 0$ is in $\{x \in \Bbb R^n : Ax = b\}$. I don't think you should use any unions at all here. And you should be very clear about what '$+$' means when there's a set involved.

Comment: Why do you say that $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n  | Ax = b\} = \{x_p \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_p = b\}\cup \{x_n \in \mathbb{R}^n | Ax_n = 0\}$?  That's not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression $x_p + N(A)$ does not stand for a union of sets; it is the set of all the points that result from adding $x_p$ to some vector $x_n$ in the nullspace. Here we are speaking of one specific vector $x_p$ which solves the equation $Ax=b$.

(That set can be called the *translation of the nullspace of $A$ by $x_p$*.)

By contrast, the union you wrote stands for the set of all points which are *either* a(any) solution to the equation $Ax=b$ *or* belong to the nullspace of A.

**Hint:**
You want to show the following equality of sets, for a given $x_p$ which satisfies $Ax_p=b$:
$$\{x\in\mathbb R^n | Ax=b\} = \{x \in \mathbb R^n| x = x_p + x_n \text{, with } Ax_n=0  \}.$$

The old-fashioned way of tackling this problem is to **show the two set inclusions** $\subseteq, \supseteq$ that imply the equality of the sets.

- For the first inclusion $(\subseteq)$: if $x$ is such that $Ax=b$ then show that it can be written as a sum of the known solution $x_p$ and some other vector in the nullspace. Think about it for a while. (Further hint: $x = x + x_p - x_p $)
- The other inclusion $(\supseteq)$ is much easier: if $y = x_p + x_n$, where $x_p$ is the known solution and $x_n$ belongs to the nullspace, show that it satisfies $Ay=b$.

Comment: @CameronBuie I meant equal to 0, obviously. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: You are welcome. +1!

Comment: Hi, so for the first set inclusion we have $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | Ax = b\} = \{x \in \mathbb{R} | A(x+x_p -x_p) = b\}$ = $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | A(x - x_p) = 0\}$, so the claim here is $x - x_p = x_n$, how can we should the latter is true?

Comment: @MathNewb Use linearity of A!

Comment: @MathNewb I highly recommend not manipulating set definitions like that for now. It is less prone to errors to leave the condition that defines the set as it is. So: first suppose that $x$ is in the set, so it verifies the condition $Ax=b$. On the other hand $x = x - x_p + x_p$, so substituting it in the condition and using linearity you show that $A(x-x_p) + A(x_p) = b$ so $A(x-x_p) = 0$. That shows that $x-x_p$ is in the nullspace. This means that we wrote $x$ as the sum of $x_p$ and a vector in the nullspace, and therefore it satisfies the condition that defines the second set.

Comment: @dafinguzman Thank you, just one last thing, so a set plus a point i.e. $\{x_n | Ax_n = 0\} + x_p$ is equivalent to that point added to every element of the set, correct i.e. $\{x_n + x_p| A(x_n + x_p) = Ax_p\}$ ? This will complete the proof.

Comment: @MathNewb Yes. But you should not mess with the condition that defines what $x_n$ is inside the set notation. $\{x_n\in\mathbb R^n|Ax_n=0\} + x_p = \{x_n + x_p | x_n\in \mathbb R^n \text{ and }Ax_n=0\}$